# IPV6 in iOS9 and configuring the IPV6 enable API

Tags: xcode, ios9, ipv6, ios9.2

My application got rejected because it was not iPV6 enabled.

I had gone through [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1) and few study on iPV6 and many other links.

But I need to understand and need some more clarification on some points related to adoption of IPV6.

1. When apple say "**IPv6-only network**" . 
   Does it mean that I can not connect with the ipv4 server via socket programming or HTTP host ?
2. To reach or communicate to the server which is ipv4 enabled, I have to adopt new apis provided by apple (nsurlsession and nscfnetwork) for http post?
3. What is synthesis ipv6 address?
   Does it mean that I will write the domain or the ipv6 address in my client (iOS application) and iOS will convert ipv6 address into ipv4 and pass it to server via my socket programming or http post ?

   To synthesis the ipv6 address this function is required: **getaddrinfo**
4. Example : I have my client(ios application) which communicate with the different server.

   a. Server1 is iPV4
   b.Server2 is ipv6

   How should I manage this ?
5. Do I need any other external entity like DNS/NAT server which will help me to convert the ipv4 into ipv6?
   OR the iOS9 and above OS does it on their own?
6. Ipv6 is compulsory from ios9.2 or from ios9 onwards?
7. My application also supports ios8.
   In which there is no requirment for the ipv6 server.
   How can I manage the code for ios8 communication to ipv4 and synthesis code in ios9 for ipv6.

Please provide me clarification and help me to understand what exactly require for the ipv6.

I am new to network side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect IPv4-Only Server only use **domian name**, not the ip address.

Or you can use a NAT64 address (usually prefix with `64:ff9b::/96`, and can be discovered by query AAAA records of IPv4 only server) when user is in a IPv6 only network.

For most developer, you are not required to do anything.

And you may try debug the App in a NAT64 network which can create by your macOS.

**Note: If you can, please use AFNetworking Library with version 3.x or higher.**

Comment: thank you for the reply.We can not give the domain name. We need to give the ip address. Because our product in based in SIP and socket programming.

Comment: you should use IPv6 Server or `64:ff9b::abcd:1234` for IPv6 Only network.  `abcd:1234` is real IPv4 in hex.

Comment: @xamrine You can certainly use host names with SIP protocol. You cannot use IPv4 addresses this way in iOS anymore.

Comment: correct，you can use domain name like `4.3.2.1.mydomain.com` for ip `1.2.3.4` with custom dns server

Comment: we cannot change our server to iPV6. Many of our customer is working fine with the IPV4.They wont prefer to use IPV6 just only because of the apple issue.

Comment: Use IPv6 `64:ff9b::abcd:1234` for IPv6 Only network.  And it can be translated IPv4 automatically.

Comment: "You can connect IPv4-Only Server only use domian name, not the ip address." This is wrong. You *can* connect to an IPv4 address perfectly fine. You just need to use the system function to synthesize an appropriate address.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

at the point when an IPv6 location isn't found, the DNS64 server asks for an IPv4 address. The DNS64 server then integrates an IPv6 address by prefixing the IPv4 address, and passes that back to the customer. In such manner, the customer dependably gets an IPv6-prepared location.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but i am having less knowledge on networking side. When you say DNS64 server. Is this server or this prefixing is handle by OS itself when we use the ios9 api or we required different external DNS server for this ?

Comment: with the help of domain you can connect

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will surely upvote your answer once i get sufficient reputation. Thank you

Comment: Hi, I recently got the same app rejection but I'm using Parse.com as my backend. Does anyone know if Parse.com API is compatible? I can't find anything on the forums so I'm very confused =\ any help would be greatly appreciated. I've attached screenshots and more explanation here: [my IPv6 issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605020/ipv6-support-using-parse-com)

Comment: The accompanying connection from Apple traces the necessities for move to IPv6 bolster so I recommend understanding it painstakingly. Apple gives rules to safeguard that your application is IPv6 perfect including which API's ought to and ought not be utilized, not hard-coding IP addresses, and so on. They even detail how to setup a neighborhood Mac-based IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 system to test against.