# IPv6 support using Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, ipv6, ios10, xcode8

My app was rejected today due to 'not supporting IPv6'. I've attached screenshots of the error they received which comes from a Parse.com API call.

I could really use some help on this, as I have no clue where to start with this.

Does anyone know if Parse.com supports IPv6? Or do I need to add something to my code? Do I need to migrate to Parse Server?

Please help =\

[image: app rejection]

[image: error they see when connected to a IPv6 network]

---- EDIT ---- 9/22/16
OK so, after my first rejection due to "IPv6" issues, I re-submitted and the app was approved. I'd still like to understand if Parse.com and Parse Server are officially IPv6 compatible but as for now, I'm just happy my app was approved. I'll keep this thread open and will edit it when I find the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The accompanying connection from Apple traces the necessities for move to IPv6 bolster so I recommend understanding it painstakingly. Apple gives rules to safeguard that your application is IPv6 perfect including which API's ought to and ought not be utilized, not hard-coding IP addresses, and so on. They even detail how to setup a neighborhood Mac-based IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 system to test against.

Comment: Yes I saw this documentation. Unfortunately I do not have the required internet adapter to setup this environment. I'm simply trying to understand if Parse.com API supports IPv6 or if I need to find a different solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a parse server hosted on Heroku which doesn't support IPv6 yet (see [here](https://kb.heroku.com/apple-has-rejected-my-application-because-heroku-does-not-support-ipv6)). But your server is not the reason why the app is rejected. It is your app which should support IPv6.

A possible solution is to download the latest Parse framework from https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/releases/tag/1.14.2 and replace the old ones. I think it should work.

Below is my comparison with the logs in the console for my app with the two different versions of Parse framework.

1. I have used Parse.framework and Bolts.framework from Feb 2016 in my Apple TV app and also just got rejected also for not supporting IPv6. I checked the log and found that

   nw_resolver_start_crazy_eyeballs_timer Received IPv4 result first, performing crazy eyeballs: waiting **50ms** on IPv6 for myapp.herokuapp.com:0.

   __nw_resolver_start_crazy_eyeballs_timer_block_invoke Crazy eyeballs timer fired: did not receive IPv6 in time, reporting only IPv4 result for myapp.herokuapp.com:0

   nw_resolver_cancel_crazy_eyeballs_timer Cancelling crazy eyeballs timer for myapp.herokuapp.com".

   It seems the performance issue comes from the 50ms when the app loads.
2. I use the latest Parse framework and no "crazy_eyeballs_timer" shows up. The log seems more promising because I can see a IPv6 address in the log now.

   nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue Starting host resolution myapp.herokuapp.com:0, flags 0x4000d000

   nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x3 ifindex=0 error=NoSuchRecord(-65554) hostname=myapp.herokuapp.com. addr=0.0.0.0:0 ttl=60

   nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x2 ifindex=0 error=NoError(0) hostname=us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com. addr=88:ffff::bbbb:afb9.0 ttl=74

Here I changed the addr of my server in the log for security reason.

I will send a new update of my app to review and I believe that it should work. I will leave a comment when it gets accepted :)

Comment: Hi Flame3, Thank you for the response. I hope your solution works. I am currently using the July 21 2016 Bolts and Parse.Framework (this was rejected and produced the above error). However, I'm still using Parse.com to host my app. I have not yet migrated to Parse Server. If your solution works, I'll migrate. Looking forward to hearing your results! Thank you!

Comment: More updates. I have submitted 4 times and didn't get proved. Then I had to skip using parse framework and use only the REST api from Parse instead. This time I still didn't get proved and I didn't know why since I have definitely nothing strange in my code. I only used Apple's own APIs. The 5th time I got the phone call from Apple and I explained that I have made the changes. They made one more test and it got approved after a couple of hours. So I am not very sure if the Parse framework is the reason. I have read the framework code roughly and didn't find anything violating the IPv6 rules.

Comment: So I resubmitted also, after getting rejected multiple times, and with no changes to the code, it was eventually approved.. no clue what is up with this...